# Base interface property not bound in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an interface `IProduct : IAuditable`

```
public interface IProduct : IAuditable
    {
        string Code { get; set; }

        string Name { get; set; }

        string Description { get; set; }

        ProductItemsList Items { get; }

        ProductType Type { get; }
    }
```

Where IAuditable is defined as:

```
public interface IAuditable
    {
        DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; }

        int CreatedBy { get; }

        DateTimeOffset ModifiedOn { get; }

        int ModifiedBy { get; }
    }
```

In a view that is bound to an enumerable of IProduct,

This works:
*(btw ReSharper tells me to remove the cast)*

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => ((IAuditable)model.ModelObject).CreatedOn)
```

But this fails:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ModelObject.CreatedOn)
```

(with error "MyProj.Products.IProduct.CreatedOn could not be found")

Can someone explain this to me. It's Friday afternoon so I'm probably being stupid.

Comment: are you sure IProduct inherits from IAuditable ? can you show us it's definition ?

Comment: Possibly [ASP.net MVC v2 - Debugging Model Binding Issues - BUG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676731/asp-net-mvc-v2-debugging-model-binding-issues-bug) and [Inherited Interface property not found by Model Binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968304/inherited-interface-property-not-found-by-model-binding)

Comment: @Selman22 I have added the IProduct interface above.

Comment: This could happen if your concrete class implements IAuditable but implements CreatedOn explicitly.  Can you show an example of a concrete class that implements IProduct